# Upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10, Images do not load, pointer does not move

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

I just upgraded to 12.04 through Upgrade Manager and the system is now unusable (after a fresh install of 11.10 had been working perfectly for 4 months.) When I log in, the icons on the Unity menu do not load. When I open the Unity menu using the Windows key, I can search and see results but again the icons do not appear. The top bar only displays my user name and the other icons appear only as 'Xs'. Most importantly, I cannot move the pointer using my trackpad or wireless USB mouse. The window switching menu does not appear when I press Ctrl+Shift so I have no way to get into the terminal to try any troubleshooting. I realize 12.04 just came out today but has anyone else experienced problems like this?

Hardware: HP Pavilion laptop. Intel Centrino processor, Intel graphics.

Comment: Can you add the hardware specs to the question, and by the way, try `ctrl-alt-t` for a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem

after some browsing I found out that the upgrade was only partially done.
Apparently some programs add blank lines in their package description breaking the apt-get tool.
(In my case it was bricscad, I read similar things about lexmark drivers)

use

sudo apt-get -f install

if it gives an errormessage complaining about blank lines in files, edit these files (delete the blank lines)
afterwards you can run

sudo apt-get upgrade

to complete the upgrade

Comment: Thanks for the help but my problem is that I can't interact with the terminal. It opens in the upper left corner (partially of the screen even) as an inactive window and I cannot move the cursor over the window to activate it. The window switching menu also will not open.

Answer (score 1):

I expirienced the same problem as you, Matt.
I could not enter anything in terminal.

**I solved it, by entering the GRUB boot menu (hitting the esc button), "e" on the first entry. then "e" on the second row (I guess it was the longest one :-)) and removed "quiet splash" at the end, and added "text" instead.**

This way it started in text mode, which enabled me to issue the commands provided by Bert (Thanks!!).

But in my case, I had to reboot before "sudo apt-get upgrade", because the network driver did not work. After reboot I finished with ".. upgrade" and another reboot let me enter my new Ubuntu 12.04 :-)

Maybe this will help you!

Comment: Well I had given up and reinstalled 11.10 from my Live CD but I will try to upgrade again and do what you said if I have the same problem. Thanks for the tip. I'll let you know how it goes!